# How to set up Windows Partition as VM in Ubuntu with VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-16.04

I recently purchased a new laptop and got it all set up with Ubuntu Gnome. I also have a Windows 10 partition on the hard drive as well. I plan to do development on windows (for Visual Studio, and .NET) and I heard that it is possible to run a virtual machine off of your existing windows partition.

My laptop is an XPS 15 9550 with a SSD. From another website (http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2016/02/running-a-real-windows-install-in-virtualbox-on-linux/) I found this command:

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk \ -filename /path/to/win10.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda \-partitions 1,4,5
```

However as you can see from the GParted screenshot below, my SSD does not appear to follow the typical convention of dev/sda/. Is it possible to run my Windows partition as a VM? And an even better question, is this even worth trying or should I just stick to dual booting when I need to develop in Windows?
[Gparted Hard Drive list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSchn.png)

Answer (score 0):

**I haven't tried this particular setup; data loss could ensue** Looks like you want `/dev/nvme0n1`. I have run cross-booting OS/VMs (OS A boots OS B and vice-versa for various combinations of Windows, Debian, Solaris, and Xen) using whole physical disks. But IMHO, running two OSes off the same hard disk simultaneously is a recipe for disaster. I also would not attempt this without a) current backups and b) regular backups going forward.

`/dev/sda` is normally the first physical SATA disk in Ubuntu; `/dev/sda1` would be the first partition, `/dev/sda2` the second, etc. It looks like the partitioning scheme for NVMe disks is `/dev/nvme0n1` for the first physical disk and the `p1`, `p2`, etc., indicate the partition.

I find VirtualBox's performance to be reasonably good, but I use disk image in a file (I use some Windows-only tools from Silicon Labs and ST Micro in a VM). I also use Vagrant and Docker for part of my build environment, but I otherwise almost exclusively use native MacOS toolchains.